# S3 storage fails with fog 0.7.2 + carrierwave master branch

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

When trying to store a file I get the following:

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:23:in `digest'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:23:in `block in setup_sha1'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:15:in `call'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:15:in `sign'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/aws.rb:309:in `signature'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/aws.rb:317:in `request'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/requests/aws/put_object.rb:43:in `put_object'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/storage/models/aws/file.rb:119:in `save'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/fog-0.7.2/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:50:in `create'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:229:in `store'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:79:in `store!'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:59:in `block in store!'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:324:in `store!'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/carrierwave-d2cb99103a4f/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:214:in `store_poster!'
... 3 levels...
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block in save'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

I've tried to debug manually and I wonder whether the issue ties in with the fact @content_type is being set as nil, although I haven't been able to deduce much further than that.

This is an s3 (or fog, I don't have any other providers) specific issue and my project works fine when using :file storage. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem just bit me. I solved it by putting this in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```rb
S3_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'amazon_s3.yml'))[Rails.env]

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage              = :s3
  config.s3_access_policy     = :public_read
  config.s3_access_key_id     = S3_CONFIG['access_key_id']
  config.s3_secret_access_key = S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key']
  config.s3_bucket            = S3_CONFIG['bucket']
end
```

and putting this in `config/amazon_s3.yml`:

```
development:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bucket: your-dev-bucket

test:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bucket: your-test-bucket

production:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bucket: your-prod-bucket
```

Comment: I am having the same issue when trying to start the server. /Users/my-machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/carrierwave-0.7.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `eval': can't convert nil into String (TypeError). Does anyone have any other notes on this issue. I copied everything from your post about but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I was using the out-dated configuration stated in the README rather than the new method stating within the documentation.

**New developers to carrierwave be sure to read the actual RDOC, not the readme.**

Comment: Could you please post the wrong and the correct configuration here? I've tried to use the configuration from the RDoc, but that makes it even worse. Maybe we are looking at different RDocs.

Comment: I tried to post my solution here, but commenting on SO is such a pain. I'm moving my comment to an "answer".